# .htaccess rewrite for multiple sub-domains

Tags: php, .htaccess, redirect

I have a server e.g. 123.123.123.123
which has two URLs pointing to it

www.mysite.com and 
api.mysite.com

how do i make it such that www.mysite.com will redirect to 123.123.123.123/front
while api.mysite.com will redirect to 123.123.123.123/api?

for www.mysite.com it shouldn't display www.mysite.com/front on the address bar.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Why are you not using virtual host?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use these 2 rules in your site root .htaccess:

```
RewriteEngine On

# route www.example.com and example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(www\.)?example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^front/ Front%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]

# route api.example.com
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule !^api/ api%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]
```

`RewriteRule !^front/` is matching a pattern using negative condition that means execute this rule if `REQUEST_URI` doesn't start with `/front/`

Comment: Yes @anubhava that is what I meant

Comment: @anubhava sorry not a pro at .htaccess so I don't quite understand this. still trying to learn, and would appreciate it if you could kindly clear this doubt for me: RewriteCond is the condition right? so `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.com$ [NC]` means if it meets api.example.com uncased. then execute `RewriteRule !^api/ api%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]` it means if the url is not api.example.com/api/ then execute api.example.com? thank you in advance.

Comment: You have interpreted it right. `^(www\.)?` combines both conditions of your answer. `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^api\.example\.com$ [NC]` means execute `RewriteRule` is host name in request is `api.example.com`. `RewriteRule !^api/ api%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NC]` means execute that rule is REQUEST_URI doesn't start with `/api/`. `api%{REQUEST_URI}` means append current URI to `/api` path.

Answer (score 0):

A partial solution of your question could be as follows:

```
    RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^example.com$
    RewriteRule ^$ http://example.com/Front/index.php
```

Comment: Would this work since OP doesn't want the URL to show the subfolder path?

Comment: yea it doesn't work. the nearest I got was RewriteRule ^(.*)$ front/$1 [L] , which would redirect www.mysite.com to 123.123.123.123/front without showing the subfolder path, but it will break api.mysite.com because it will be searching for 123.123.123.123/front/api/

Comment: You need to create multiple rules as rules ladder. To create so, you can use the one you come up with or you can use the one I gave in the about. You need to craft the solution based on these

Answer (score 0):

Not very good with htaccess, but I managed to get it working with these:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} www.mysite.com [NC,OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^mysite.com [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ front/$1 [L]
```

Comment: You don't need 2 sepate conditions. See my answer above.

Comment: yea I realised it's very similar, `^(www\.)?` combines both conditions. I'm not sure how the second line works. shall comment below.